# how to remove duplicate words matching the pattern from every line of a file in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a file something like below

```
LINE 1:
type,rcpt,dlvSourceIp,timeLogged,header_Message-Id,bounceCat,dsnStatus,dsnDiag

LINE 2: d,olaj,asjdfuyjdv,2014-02-07
14-08560,<13.e0.IM.45.811MSOSI1.102O@maien.com>,suc,2.0.0
(success),smtp;250 ok dirdel <13.e0.IM.45.811MSOSI1.102O@maien.com>

LINE 3: d,olaj,asjdfuyjdv,2014-02-07
14-08560,2014-02-07
17:30:14-0800,<1060.eb40.IGNM.1335313.816310169MSOSI1.10S@kashfgjqd.Ighrs.com>,suc,2.0.0 (success),smtp; jgfjasd jsydsj
<13960.e0.Igdf.1335313.816310I1.10@gsdfdrs.Iyre.com> Queued mail for
delivery
```

Now i want to remove the 2nd occurence of the words which are in between <>.

**expected output:**

```
LINE 1:
type,rcpt,dlvSourceIp,timeLogged,header_Message-Id,bounceCat,dsnStatus,dsnDiag

LINE 2: d,olaj,asjdfuyjdv,2014-02-07
14-08560,<13.e0.IM.45.811MSOSI1.102O@maien.com>,suc,2.0.0
(success),smtp;250 ok dirdel

LINE 3: d,olaj,asjdfuyjdv,2014-02-07 14-08560,2014-02-07
17:30:14-0800,<1060.eb40.IGNM.1335313.816310169MSOSI1.10S@kashfgjqd.Ighrs.com>,suc,2.0.0 (success),smtp; jgfjasd jsydsj Queued mail for delivery
```

As in out put second occurrence of data between < and > is removed...

I have tried below command but it is deleting all matching strings.. But i want only 2nd string to be removed.

```
sed 's/<.*.>//' test.txt
```

Any help is really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
sed 's/\(<[^>]*>\)\(.*\)\(<[^>]*>\)/\1\2/' test.txt
```

1. Check for < >
2. Then check for any text
3. then check for second < >

Output:
Only 1 and 2

Comment: Good point, I missed the bit between the groups. And I see you've spotted the need for the character class :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a back reference to refer to the pattern just matched, like this:

```
sed 's/\(<[^>]*>\)\(.*\)<[^>]*>/\1\2/'
```

The other change you need is the character class, to stop `<.*>` matching everything in between the first `<` and last `>`.

ETA: allow for the second group between `<>` being different to the first, as pointed out by Abhishek.

Comment: The second < > may contain a different text, so IMO you cannot refer it as \1

Comment: I see what you mean - line 2 of the input has them the same, but line 3 has them different!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//2' file
```